# Jquery script to catch link click events for Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, universal, analytics.js

I am trying to set up event tracking via Google Universal analytics. I found a script example that would appear to do exactly what I need - i.e. track various anchor clicks in the page and categorize them accordingly. However my javascript understanding is still rudimentary and I need help to understand why this script would not work. Basically click events appear not to be triggered at all. I checked - the script is loaded alright and can display an alertbox just upon loading. The script is placed the last in the head part of the page, after the analytics.js and Jquery are loaded.

Hopefully this is something obvious that I am missing, many thanks. Robert

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|dmg|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|rar|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav)$/i;
    var baseHref = '';
    if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
    var hrefRedirect = '';

    jQuery('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        var el = jQuery(this);
        var track = true;
        var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') : '';
        var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
        if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
            var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
            if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
                elEv.category = 'email';
                elEv.action = 'click';
                elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
                elEv.loc = href;
            }
            else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
                var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                elEv.category = 'download';
                elEv.action = 'click-' + extension[0];
                elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,'-');
                elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
            }
            else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
                elEv.category = 'external';
                elEv.action = 'click';
                elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                elEv.non_i = true;
                elEv.loc = href;

            }
            else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && isThisDomain) {
                elEv.category = 'internal';
                elEv.action = 'click';
                elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                elEv.non_i = true;
                elEv.loc = href;

            }            
            else if (href.match(/^tel\:/i)) {
                elEv.category = 'telephone';
                elEv.action = 'click';
                elEv.label = href.replace(/^tel\:/i, '');
                elEv.loc = href;
            }
            else track = false;


            if (track) {
                var ret = true;

                if((elEv.category == 'external' || elEv.category == 'download') && (el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') ) {
                    hrefRedirect = elEv.loc;

                    ga('send','event', elEv.category.toLowerCase(),elEv.action.toLowerCase(),elEv.label.toLowerCase(),elEv.value,{
                        'nonInteraction': elEv.non_i ,
                        'hitCallback':gaHitCallbackHandler
                    });

                    ret = false;
                }
                else {
                    ga('send','event', elEv.category.toLowerCase(),elEv.action.toLowerCase(),elEv.label.toLowerCase(),elEv.value,{
                        'nonInteraction': elEv.non_i
                    });
                }

                return ret;
            }
        }
    });

    gaHitCallbackHandler = function() {
        window.location.href = hrefRedirect;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: whether jQuery is loaded? is it loaded before this script? is there any error in the browser console

Comment: is the script added inside `head` or `body`

Comment: is there an element called `base` in the page with an href property

Comment: where did you add the `alert` statement to test the script

Comment: did you try my code... I had added a dom ready handler to it...

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this - I added base tag to the page, but I did not see where you had changed the code - so no I had not tried it yet and now your code appears to be gone.

Comment: I added a line `jQuery(function(){` after the if condition and `});` before the end of the condition... check my answer below

Comment: Also I had responded that script is the last in head and that alert code was placed immediately after  else track = false;strange - my comment also appears to have vanished.

Comment: I had deleted the answer since it looked like not fixing the problem... for now I have enabled it again... you can check it

Comment: Thanks this looks great, part of the code is definitely working. Now the external and mailto bits are catching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have given there are few things that can go wrong there

1. There is no `base` tag in the page. You need to have a `<base href="" />` in the page
2. The script is added inside `head` . Then the `body` element is still not loaded so you need to add the script inside dom ready handler/register the delegated handler to `document` object instead of `body`

Assuming jQuery is loaded correctly and it is added before this script try

```
<base href="yourbaseurl" />
```

then

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    jQuery(function(){
        var filetypes = /\.(zip|exe|dmg|pdf|doc.*|xls.*|ppt.*|mp3|txt|rar|wma|mov|avi|wmv|flv|wav)$/i;
        var baseHref = '';
        if (jQuery('base').attr('href') != undefined) baseHref = jQuery('base').attr('href');
        var hrefRedirect = '';

        jQuery('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) {

            var el = jQuery(this);
            var track = true;
            var href = (typeof(el.attr('href')) != 'undefined' ) ? el.attr('href') : '';
            var isThisDomain = href.match(document.domain.split('.').reverse()[1] + '.' + document.domain.split('.').reverse()[0]);
            if (!href.match(/^javascript:/i)) {
                var elEv = []; elEv.value=0, elEv.non_i=false;
                if (href.match(/^mailto\:/i)) {
                    elEv.category = 'email';
                    elEv.action = 'click';
                    elEv.label = href.replace(/^mailto\:/i, '');
                    elEv.loc = href;
                }
                else if (href.match(filetypes)) {
                    var extension = (/[.]/.exec(href)) ? /[^.]+$/.exec(href) : undefined;
                    elEv.category = 'download';
                    elEv.action = 'click-' + extension[0];
                    elEv.label = href.replace(/ /g,'-');
                    elEv.loc = baseHref + href;
                }
                else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && !isThisDomain) {
                    elEv.category = 'external';
                    elEv.action = 'click';
                    elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                    elEv.non_i = true;
                    elEv.loc = href;

                }
                else if (href.match(/^https?\:/i) && isThisDomain) {
                    elEv.category = 'internal';
                    elEv.action = 'click';
                    elEv.label = href.replace(/^https?\:\/\//i, '');
                    elEv.non_i = true;
                    elEv.loc = href;

                }            
                else if (href.match(/^tel\:/i)) {
                    elEv.category = 'telephone';
                    elEv.action = 'click';
                    elEv.label = href.replace(/^tel\:/i, '');
                    elEv.loc = href;
                }
                else track = false;


                if (track) {
                    var ret = true;

                    if((elEv.category == 'external' || elEv.category == 'download') && (el.attr('target') == undefined || el.attr('target').toLowerCase() != '_blank') ) {
                        hrefRedirect = elEv.loc;

                        ga('send','event', elEv.category.toLowerCase(),elEv.action.toLowerCase(),elEv.label.toLowerCase(),elEv.value,{
                            'nonInteraction': elEv.non_i ,
                            'hitCallback':gaHitCallbackHandler
                        });

                        ret = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        ga('send','event', elEv.category.toLowerCase(),elEv.action.toLowerCase(),elEv.label.toLowerCase(),elEv.value,{
                            'nonInteraction': elEv.non_i
                        });
                    }

                    return ret;
                }
            }
        });

        var gaHitCallbackHandler = function() {
            window.location.href = hrefRedirect;
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I added alertbox after else track = false; now I added the base tag. The script is the last script in the head.

Comment: This is very useful - now I need to work a bit on why internal links don't seem to be catching

Comment: I slept 4 hours, probably we are in different timezones

Comment: @r0berts where are you from

Comment: Thanks again sorry, I can't vote yet, reputation too low, but I will try to check the rest of the code so that when I check this answer the code would be ready for anyone else to use with all bits functioning, is that OK?

Comment: I live in London. And you?

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this is great. It now works as expected. I did a few custom tweaks to match my page needs - such as where downloads are coming from and how image clicks are tracked and all bits do work. Were it not for you I would be struggling still, since I don't really know javascript. Thanks a lot again! Rob